# Case statement to switch the column being compared in sql where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, where-clause

I have a scenario where the column that I need to use in the where clause changes based on the value of a variable.

For example if @ID matches the TableID in Table1 then I'll use the code below

```
WHERE 
    Table1.TableID = CASE WHEN @ID= -1 THEN Table1.TableID ELSE @ID END
```

However, if the @ID matches the TableID of Table2 Then I need to use

```
WHERE 
    Table2.TableID = CASE WHEN @ID= -1 THEN Table2.TableID ELSE @ID END
```

How will I accomplish this? Will the OR clause work in this scenario?

Edit: Trying to provide more detail to make it more clear. 
Sample data

Table 1

```
TableID   
1
2
3
4
```

Table 2

```
TableID
10
11
12
13
```

If the @ID = -1 I want to see all the rows from both the tables.

If @ID = 1 then only show the first row from Table 1

If @ID = 10 then only show the last row from Table 2...and so on.

Comment: Your narrative and code snippets are quite confusing. Could you give some sample data, a complete (small query), some `@ID` values and the expected results in each case?

Comment: yes, an OR will work.

Comment: Any clarification coming down the pipeline on this Q?

Comment: Sorry if my question wasn't clear enough. I'll provide some scenarios to help you guys understand this better. Although I do think one of the answers below will accomplish what I want.

Comment: @Mogambo: Please read [John Skeets Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [StackOverflow: How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Couldn't you just do something like this.

```
where (@ID = Table1.TableID OR @ID = Table2.TableID)
```

If you are looking to see if @ID matches either of these tableID's than this seems like a much simpler way of doing it.

Comment: I'm not sure he actually wants the -1 I left a comment on that but it was never addressed.

Comment: On the original post, the `@ID = -1` case resolve to `TableX.TableID = TableX.TableID`, which is always true (unless `TableX.TableID` can be `NULL`).

Comment: `@ID IN (Table1.TableID, Table2.TableID, -1)`

Comment: I do need the -1. Marked this as the answer and upvoted @rselmos comment. TableID will never be null

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this....

```
WHERE 
   (@ID = -1  AND Table1.TableID = @ID)
  OR
   (@ID = -1  AND Table2.TableID = @ID)
```

It doesnt make sense the way you have asked the question, you have same value in both cases for `@ID` it could have been a simpler query something like this...

```
WHERE 
   (Table1.TableID = @ID)
  OR
   (Table2.TableID = @ID)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE @ID IN (
  Table1.TableID
 ,Table2.TableID
 ,-1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this minimal sum of products clause. Given the information available, this is the most I can tell you to do without blindly guessing at the structure of your query and DB:

```
WHERE
(Table1.TableID = @ID AND @ID <> -1) OR (Table2.TableID = @ID AND @ID <> -1)
```

Comment: please elaborate on your answer, or at least make it a complete SQL query

Comment: I mean, I would if I could man. The question doesn't exactly give me much to work with.

Comment: @Philip THe OP doesn't really give anything other than the sinipit of a `WHERE` clause there isn't much to work with here. We probably all should have not spent our time on it in the first place.